# Login to Way2sms through LWP failing

Tags: perl, authentication, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am trying to login to [Way2sms](http://site2.way2sms.com/content/index.html) through LWP. The source code of the page says that the login form (which, in this case, appears to be the root node of everything within the body) has an action attribute of `''`, which I read in some other Stackoverflow post, points to the URL of the page containing that form. The `name` attribute for the mobile and password fields are available from the source code, so I tried this:

```
use URI;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use LWP;
open f, "> way2sms.txt";
$browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent=>'Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Windows NT 5.0; U)');
$resp = $browser->post("http://site2.way2sms.com/content/index.html",[username=>$username,password=>$password]);
if ( $resp->is_redirect ) {
    $resp = $browser->get( $resp->header('Location') );
}

print f $resp->content;
close f;
```

With the correct phone-number and passwords, the submission should return a personalized page, which among other things, contains a message like **Welcome, Kaustav Mukherjee**. So naturally, I expect the code to print out 5. However, although **Logged** is printed out denoting success, the 5 isn't printed out, showing that the login failed. How to do it? (Please don't suggest using `Mechanize`!)

Comment: I noticed that you use `$rsp` on the 4th line and `$resp` everywhere else.  I assume that's a typo?

Comment: Yeah yeah, that's a typo. Corrected it here!

Comment: Have you examined `$resp->content`?  Does it contain 'Kaustav'? Perhaps it's encoded?  Maybe you could print it out and post it?  There is another function `decoded_content` described [here](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.03/lib/HTTP/Response.pm) that might be helpful

Comment: Yeah I just did. Strange result, the entire output file contains two lines of text:

**Can't connect to site2.way2sms.com:80 (Bad hostname)

LWP::Protocol::http::Socket: Bad hostname 'site2.way2sms.com' at C:/Perl/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that you get is a `302 Moved Temporarily` and not a `200 OK`. Therefore, you need to fetch the content of the new page and not the content of the redirect response.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    agent =>
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
    cookie_jar => {},
);
my $response = $ua->post(
    'http://site2.way2sms.com/Login1.action',
    {
        username => '1234567890',
        password => 'topsecret',
    }
);
if ( $response->is_redirect ) {
    $response = $ua->get( $response->header('Location') );
    print $response->decoded_content;
}
```

Some comments on your code:

- Always [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html)
- [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) or manually check if [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) succeeded or not
- Prefer three argument [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- Prefer lexical filehandles (`open my $fh, …`)
- If you use barewords for filehandles make sure that they are capitalised ([`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) will warn you)

Comment: Yeah, with this fix, a chunk of HTML is now pasted in the file alright, but still my name is missing! I just went through the HTML returned. One of the numerous `script` tags contain a function like: `function validate(){

     var ddiv1 = window.parent.document.documentElement;

  ddiv1.scrollTop = ddiv1.scrollTop + 60;

    

     if(document.loginform.username.value==0){

       alert("Please Enter Login ID");

       return false;

     }`, suggesting that it's still in the login page, for the same function shows up in the original page's source code.

Comment: You had better *check* your login details (or you are doing it wrong) as I have just confirmed that it works. It does even list a `logout2()` function.

Comment: Trust me, there is nothing wrong with the username and password! I am updating my question with the modified code, do replace the username  password and name by yours and check whether the file `way2sms.txt` contains your name!

Comment: Just noted that the page to which you posted the username and password is wrong. See my code for the correct URL.

Comment: Ok I will try it right away. But where from you got the URL? I was using the URL of the login page itself, since the loginform had a blank value for the `action` attribute.

Comment: Ok, I just found out, you got that from the function `validate`'s last line, which runs like `document.loginform.action ="../Login1.action";`. However, the form is in the page http://site5.way2sms.com/content/index.html, so a `../Login1.action` should make the URL http://site5.way2sms.com/content/Login1.action, but you are using http://site2.way2sms.com/Login1.action. How come?

Comment: Sorry, I just rediscovered, the code works even with http://www.site5.way2sms.com/content/Login1.action. In fact, even with arbitrary URL'S, containing anything in between, like http://www.site5.way2sms.com/content/baz/bar/booze/Login1.action works. Looks like the PHP does a redirection whenever there is a URL ending with `Login1.action`. However in that case, the source code should have contained just `/Login1.action` as the value of the `action` attribute, don't you think so?